# Pako not able to deflate gzip files generated in python

Tags: javascript, python, angular, gzip, pako

I'm generating gzip files from python using the following code: (using python 3)

```
    file = gzip.open('output.json.gzip', 'wb')
    dataToWrite = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    file.write(dataToWrite)
    file.close()
```

However, I'm trying to read this file now in Javascript using the Pako library (I'm using Angular 2):

```
this.http.get("output.json.gzip")
      .map((res:Response) => {
        var resText:any = new Uint8Array(res.arrayBuffer());
        var result = "";
        try {
          result = pako.inflate(resText, {"to": "string"});
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("Error " + err);
        }
        return result;

      });
```

But I'm getting this error in the console: `unknown compression method`. Should I be doing something else to properly inflate gzip files?

Comment: You've encoded it into utf-8.  Where do you decode it?

Comment: How do I decode it using JS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to use the res.blob() function to get the true binary data, not res.arrayBuffer(); and then convert the blob to the array buffer:

```
return this.http.get("output.json.gzip", new RequestOptions({ responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }))
      .map((res:Response) => {
        var blob = res.blob();
        var arrayBuffer;
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function() {
            arrayBuffer = this.result;
            try {
              let result:any = pako.ungzip(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer), {"to": "string"});
              let obj = JSON.parse(result);
              console.log(obj);
            } catch (err) {
              console.log("Error " + err);
            }
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        return "abc";
      });
```

Comment: This worked beautifully for me except I had to replace `arrayBuffer = this.result;` with `arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;`.